# Splash screen displays previous installed app after uninstalling and reinstalling different app android

Tags: android, reactjs, caching, mobile, capacitor

I have three apps, which are basically the same app but with different names, badges, color schemes and splash screen.
I've noticed on Android devices when app1 has been installed, opened then deleted, if I download app2, when opening the app the splash screen of the previous app displays.
It seems to be a caching issue.
Has anyone faced this issue before and has some advice on where to start looking to reset a cache on uninstall?